# Page not showing up for GUI python

Tags: python

i got an error of "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"
so i have written some code for my GUI and i wanted a new page after selecting a file.

```
class Application(tk.Frame):              
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)   
        self.grid()                       
        self.quit_program()
        self.browse_file()(self, text="Create new window", 
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(side='top')

    def create_window(self):
        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
        l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
        options['filetypes'] = [('musicfiles', '.mp3'),('videofiles','.mp4')]

        options['parent'] = self
        options['title'] = 'This is a title'

    def quit_program(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
          command=self.quit)            
        self.quitButton.grid()

    def browse_file(self):
        self.browseButton = tk.Button(self, text='Browse',command=self.askopenfile)
        self.browseButton.grid()
    def askopenfile(self):
        return tkFileDialog.askopenfile(**self.file_opt )

app = Application()                       
app.master.title('Sample application')    
app.mainloop()
```

Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/121794/Desktop/FYPtestGUI.py",
 line 39, in <module> app = Application()
 File "C:/Users/121794/Desktop/FYPtestGUI.py",
 line 11, in init command=self.create_window)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please *always* post the complete traceback. Especially in this case it will point you to the failing line in code.

Comment: @msvalkon sorry just that the website doesn't allow me to upload the whole code

Comment: @msvalkon                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/121794/Desktop/FYPtestGUI.py", line 39, in <module>
    app = Application()
  File "C:/Users/121794/Desktop/FYPtestGUI.py", line 11, in __init__
    command=self.create_window)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
self.browse_file()(self,
    text    = "Create new window", 
    command = self.create_window
)
```

You are calling `browse_file()`, expecting it to return a function, and calling that function. Now this:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

This is telling you that `browse_file()` returned `None`, and you called it. `None` (an object of type `NoneType`) is not a function, that is to say, `is not callable`.

Your code for `browse_file`:

```
def browse_file(self):
    self.browseButton = tk.Button(self, text='Browse',command=self.askopenfile)
    self.browseButton.grid()
```

You don't return anything explicitly, so this function returns `None` (giving `None is not callable`), but you don't accept parameters either (so removing the extra `()` in the code above is also erroneus).

I'm not sure what it is you want to do.

Comment: i am expecting to go to a new page after selecting the file.quite confused on how to do that though.

Comment: I'm confused as well :) if you can't explain it to us, you should first try and understand the problem better. What I do when I find myself in your predicament is devote an hour, perhaps two, to reading documentation, blog posts and examples. Understanding makes everything easier, even if you're not reading how to solve your specific problem of the moment.